# Converting a Array of String to a Float Then Finding the Average of the Converted Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a for loop that will get the average of a array of Strings that need to be converted to floats. When I run this I get the correct sum value only inside of the loop but when I try to log 'sum' outside of the for loop it is equal to 'NaN and 'average' is equal to 'NaN' outside of the for loop . I am relatively new to JavaScript and web development as a whole so a well explained and simple response of what I did wrong and how I can fix it would be very greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
var myArray = ["4.5333422323", "3.4345355", "2.535563435"];
var sum = 0.0;

//Should run loop 3 times
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
        //Should change the String inside of myArray[x] to its Float form
        myArray[x] = parseFloat(myArray[x]);

        //Adds the Float form of myArray[x] to the pre existing sum
        sum += myArray[x];
        console.log("The current sum is: " + sum);
}
//Should compute the the average of myArray
var average = sum / parseFloat(myArray.length);
console.log("The total average is: " + average);
```

Comment: After the 'for' loop. sum = NaN and average = Nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myArray = ["4.5333422323", "3.4345355", "2.535563435"];
var sum = 0.0;

//Should run loop 3 times
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
        //Should change the String inside of myArray[x] to its Float form
        myArray[x] = +(myArray[x]);

        //Adds the Float form of myArray[x] to the pre existing sum
        sum += myArray[x];
        console.log("The current sum is: " + sum);
}
//Should compute the the average of myArray
var average = sum / (myArray.length);
console.log("The total average is: " + average);
```

Try this.

Comment: Where you are accessing this sum variable and how you are accessing it.Show us how you are accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map jQuery to get Sum of all Array elements.

Code is as Follows :

```
var myArray = ["4.5333422323", "3.4345355", "2.535563435"];
var sum = 0.0;
myArray.map(function(val){ 
    sum += parseFloat(val);
});
var average = sum / myArray.length;
console.log("The total average is: " + average);
```

If you want to convert array to float then:

```
var myArray = ["4.5333422323", "3.4345355", "2.535563435"];
var sum = 0.0;
myArray = myArray.map(function(val){ 
    sum += parseFloat(val);
    return parseFloat(val);
});
var average = sum / myArray.length;
console.log("The total average is: " + average);
```

Comment: Cool, but it's better to use [].forEach() since [].map() is meant to be used when returning values to a new array.

Comment: yes zvona you are right ! But he also needs to Convert a Array of String to a Float and then Finding the Average of the Converted Array

Answer (score 0):

`myArray.length` is already a number :

```
var average = sum / myArray.length;
```

Comment: Console still logs sum = NaN and average = NaN after the 'for' loop

Answer (score 0):

You may have something else in your code that overrides parseFloat with a custom function that does not always return a number. Be careful about that.